# How to replace plugin icon?

Tags: plugin-development, icon

Could be a silly question, sorry for this but is my first wordpress plugin. I would like to change the icon that appears in the update page:

[image]

How to do this? Unfortunately I cannot find anything in the doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the plugin directory assets page in the Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-assets/#plugin-icons), create one or more of the following, relative to your plugin root directory:

- `assets/icon-128x128.(png|jpg)`
- `assets/icon-256x256.(png|jpg)`
- `assets/icon.svg`